# django using values form values_list as object

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have a queryset:

```
some = Something.objects.values_list('organisation', flat=True)
```

it gives me list of some organisations. Now in my template I want to access the id of organisation.

```
{% for org in some %}
    {{org.id}}
{% endfor %}
```

Here `{{org.id}}` not giving the id of the organisation but when I do `{{org}}` only it gives me name of the organisation. How can I get id of organisation here ?

Thank you

Comment: Replace `values_list` with `filter` to get queryset object using which you can get `org.id` in your template.

Comment: some will be a list of organization (field) such as ["org1", "org2"]. I think you are looking for a full query set. user filter instead.

Answer (score 2):

Using `values`

```
some = Something.objects.values('organisation', 'id')
```

In template use `{{ some.organisation }}` and `{{ some.id }}`.

Answer (score 0):

`Something.objects.values_list('organisation', flat=True)` is not a queryset object, it returns a list of organisation names. If you need a queryset, use `filter()` instead.